Fantasy movie including magical mirror and evil wizard
From vague childhood memories: a fantasy movie in a medieval setting, where an evil wizard uses a mirror to transform people in evil counterpart. When such a transformed person then stands in front of a mirror, her evil nature is shown.
The movie must be at least 40 years old, maybe quite older. I don't remember if in color or b/w. Both might be the case. It is not an animated movie.

You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Is this a duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/290858/16184?

Is this Jack the Giant Killer (1962)...?

A farmboy-turned-knight must protect a princess from the schemes of an evil wizard.

This is a fantasy adventure film reminiscent of the Sinbad films that were made around the same time.
The plot involves an evil wizard named Pendragon who kidnaps Princess Elaine of Cornwall in an attempt to force her father to surrender the throne to him. While Elaine is being held prisoner in Pendragon's castle, he bewitches her to make her loyal to him. This also has the effect of transforming her clothing and making her look somewhat inhuman, with green skin and yellow eyes.
Pendragon then casts an illusion on Elaine to make her look like her normal self, in order to fool the hero, Jack, but Elaine's evil appearance is still reflected in a mirror, and Jack is able to free her from Pendragon's spell by smashing the mirror while her reflection is visible in it.







Amazing! I was looking for it for half an eternity. Thank you!
